# Active storage rails save the blobs and attachments data but no file in storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-activestorage

I'm using spree to develop online shop application. User want to have upload file image inside the cart form (of course the data will have auto deleted in several hours if doesnt make the next step). It will have one attachment for one selected variant. So because it use active storage, I must declare `has_one_attached :user_file_attachment`  inside `line_item.rb`. and inside `add_item.rb` i'm using those code

```
if line_item.nil?
    opts = ::Spree::PermittedAttributes.line_item_attributes.flatten.each_with_object({}) do |attribute, result|
    result[attribute] = options[attribute]
    end.merge(currency: order.currency).delete_if { |_key, value| value.nil? }

    line_item = order.line_items.new(quantity: quantity,
                                           variant: variant,
                                           options: opts)
else
    line_item.quantity += quantity.to_i
end

# here where i place the code to attach the file. I'm using dummy method first.
line_item.user_file_attachment.attach(
            io: File.open('D:\SamplePic\Sample.jpg'),
            content_type: 'image/jpeg',
            filename: 'file_' + Time.zone.now.to_s + '.jpg'
)
```

it create the `[active_storage_blobs]` data and `[active_storage_attachments]` data. but if I check inside Storage, there's nothing created.

But. If i'm using `order` instead of `line_item`, it create the data blobs, attachments, and file inside the storage.

```
# here where i place the code to attach the file. I'm using dummy method first.
order.user_file_attachment.attach(
            io: File.open('D:\SamplePic\Sample.jpg'),
            content_type: 'image/jpeg',
            filename: 'file_' + Time.zone.now.to_s + '.jpg'
)
```

If I check `order.user_file_attachment.attached?` and `line_item.user_file_attachment.attached?` both is return true. But I see in the console, order one have statement `Disk Storage (9.3ms) Uploaded file to key....`

```
Spree::Order Update (0.9ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE [spree_orders] SET [payment_state] = @0, [shipment_state] = @1, [item_total] = @2, [item_count] = @3, [adjustment_total] = @4, [included_tax_total] = @5, [additional_tax_total] = @6, [payment_total] = @7, [shipment_total] = @8, [promo_total] = @9, [total] = @10, [updated_at] = @11 WHERE [spree_orders].[id] = @12; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRows', N'@0 nvarchar(4000), @1 nvarchar(4000), @2 decimal(10,2), @3 int, @4 decimal(10,2), @5 decimal(10,2), @6 decimal(10,2), @7 decimal(10,2), @8 decimal(10,2), @9 decimal(10,2), @10 decimal(10,2), @11 datetime2(6), @12 int', @0 = NULL, @1 = NULL, @2 = N'4.5', @3 = 1, @4 = N'0.0', @5 = N'0.0', @6 = N'0.0', @7 = N'0.0', @8 = N'0.0', @9 = N'0.0', @10 = N'4.5', @11 = '01-27-2021 09:45:35.150663', @12 = 1  [["payment_state", nil], ["shipment_state", nil], ["item_total", nil], ["item_count", nil], ["adjustment_total", nil], ["included_tax_total", nil], ["additional_tax_total", nil], ["payment_total", nil], ["shipment_total", nil], ["promo_total", nil], ["total", nil], ["updated_at", nil], ["id", nil]]
  ↳ app/models/spree/order_updater.rb:105:in `persist_totals'
  Spree::Order Update (3.2ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE [spree_orders] SET [updated_at] = @0 WHERE [spree_orders].[id] = @1; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS AffectedRows', N'@0 datetime2(6), @1 int', @0 = '01-27-2021 09:45:34.429746', @1 = 1  [["updated_at", nil], ["id", nil]]
  ↳ app/services/spree/cart/add_item.rb:7:in `call'
  SQL (2.1ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  ↳ app/services/spree/cart/add_item.rb:7:in `call'
  Disk Storage (9.3ms) Uploaded file to key: k69f7oi6lw6syk9v9evzkju3hkbx (checksum: orCuROlkMY7nw54l/uQ+DQ==)
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 3a364a95-9757-4cf9-b501-688f6cada68e) to Async(active_storage_analysis) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x0000000012aa2230 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://spree-ecommerce/ActiveStorage::Blob/570>>
```

But if i'm using line_item, it wont have `Disk Storage (9.3ms) Uploaded file to key...`

By the way, correct me if i'm wrong. I'm still new using Spree, still learning the structure also.

Answer (score 0):

Already found the way. But I dont know is there any better way or not. Feel free to comment what my mistake. ;).

I looked at what output and what possibility I can make, I found that: I CAN'T put these code inside `add_item.rb` even make another function/procedure for this function inside this file. Then, I notice that only the first time the problem has occurred, for the second time I submitted, The code is working as intended.

So, instead in `add_item.rb`, I put it in `cart_controller.rb` after `result` inside `add_item` procedure.

```
def add_item
    spree_authorize! :update, spree_current_order, order_token
    spree_authorize! :show, @variant
    result = add_item_service.call(
        order: spree_current_order,
        variant: @variant,
        quantity: params[:quantity],
        options: params[:options]
    )

    # result.value = its line_item obj

    # here where i place the code to attach the file. I'm using dummy method first.
    result.value.user_file_attachment.attach(
        io: File.open('D:\SamplePic\Sample.jpg'),
        content_type: 'image/jpeg',
        filename: 'file_' + Time.zone.now.to_s + '.jpg'
    )

    render_order(result)
end
```